# String to Json object to Json Array in Java

Tags: java, json, gson

Need to convert below json response to Json object and then "update" field should be converted to json array.
Basically needs to fetch each key, value pair.

```
 {
"Response": [
    {
        "TicketID": "200",
        "update": [
            {
                "Type": "Group",
                "user": "ABC",
                "groupName": "RTT",
                "updatetime": "1465367505863"
            },
            {
                "Type": "status",
                "user": "ABC",
                "status": "Open",
                "updatetime": "1465367505858"
            },
            {
                "Type": "comment",
                "user": "ABC",
                "comments": "Updating ",
                "updatetime": "1465367505854"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "TicketID": "300",
        "update": [
            {
                "Type": "Group",
                "user": "ABC",
                "groupName": "RTT",
                "updatetime": "1465367505863"
            },
            {
                "Type": "status",
                "user": "ABC",
                "status": "Open",
                "updatetime": "1465367505854"
            },
            {
                "Type": "comment",
                "user": "ABC",
                "comments": "Updating Group",
                "updatetime": "1465367505834"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I have tried below code :-

```
                    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(ticket.getBytes());
    // create json reader from json
    JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(is);

    // get the jsonobject structure from JsonReader
    JsonObject ticObj = reader.readObject();

    JsonArray arrTicket = ticObj.getJsonArray("update");
    String tktid=ticObj.getString("TicketID");
    System.out.println("Ticket id is "+tktid);

    System.out.println("ticket Id =>");

    for (javax.json.JsonValue value : arrTicket) {
        String ticketid = value.toString();
        System.out.print(" " + ticketid + "\n");

    }
```

Getting below error as "javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 84 at (line no=1, column no=16, offset=15)"

Comment: `update` belongs to the `Response` JSON Object

Comment: The Json you provided seems to be invalid use this tool to validate it:- http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO it like this:

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{" +
                "\"Response\": [" +
                "    {" +
                "        \"TicketID\": \"200\"," +
                "        \"update\": [" +
                "            {" +
                "                \"Type\": \"Group\"," +
                "                \"user\": \"ABC\"," +
                "                \"groupName\": \"RTT\"," +
                "                \"updatetime\": \"1465367505863\"" +
                "            }," +
                "            {" +
                "                \"Type\": \"status\"," +
                "                \"user\": \"ABC\"," +
                "                \"status\": \"Open\"," +
                "                \"updatetime\": \"1465367505858\"" +
                "            }," +
                "            {" +
                "                \"Type\": \"comment\"," +
                "                \"user\": \"ABC\"," +
                "                \"comments\": \"Updating \"," +
                "                \"updatetime\": \"1465367505854\"" +
                "            }" +
                "        ]" +
                "    }," +
                "    {" +
                "        \"TicketID\": \"300\"," +
                "        \"update\": [" +
                "            {" +
                "                \"Type\": \"Group\"," +
                "                \"user\": \"ABC\"," +
                "                \"groupName\": \"RTT\"," +
                "                \"updatetime\": \"1465367505863\"" +
                "            }," +
                "            {" +
                "                \"Type\": \"status\"," +
                "                \"user\": \"ABC\"," +
                "                \"status\": \"Open\"," +
                "                \"updatetime\": \"1465367505854\"" +
                "            }," +
                "            {" +
                "                \"Type\": \"comment\"," +
                "                \"user\": \"ABC\"," +
                "                \"comments\": \"Updating Group\"," +
                "                \"updatetime\": \"1465367505834\"" +
                "            }" +
                "        ]" +
                "    }" +
                "]" +
                "}");

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("Response");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String TicketID = object.optString("TicketID");

            System.out.println("TicketID ----"+TicketID);

            JSONArray update = object.getJSONArray("update");

            for (int j = 0; j < update.length(); j++) {

                JSONObject obj = update.getJSONObject(j);

                String Type = obj.optString("Type");
                System.out.println("Type :"+i+":"+Type);
                String user = obj.optString("user");
                System.out.println("user :"+i+":"+user);
                String groupName = obj.optString("groupName");
                System.out.println("groupName :"+i+":"+groupName);
                String updatetime = obj.optString("updattime");
                System.out.println("updatetime :"+i+":"+updatetime);
            }

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSON reponse and add them in response list model and this models can be queried later as per requirement. Since the response is not consistent make sure to check for keys every time you parse response to avoid crashes.

```
String response = "JSON Response String";

    ArrayList<ResponseModel> responseModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONObject rootJsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray responseJsonArray = new JSONArray(rootJsonObject.getString("Response"));

        for (int i = 0; i < responseJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject childJsonObject = new JSONObject(responseJsonArray.get(i).toString());
            String str_ticketID = childJsonObject.getString("TicketID");
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(childJsonObject.getString("update"));

            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject updateChildJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(j).toString());

                ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel();
                responseModel.type = updateChildJsonObject.getString("Type");
                responseModel.user = updateChildJsonObject.getString("user");

                if (updateChildJsonObject.has("groupName"))
                    responseModel.groupName = updateChildJsonObject.getString("groupName");

                if (updateChildJsonObject.has("status"))
                    responseModel.status = updateChildJsonObject.getString("status");

                if (updateChildJsonObject.has("comments"))
                    responseModel.comments = updateChildJsonObject.getString("comments");

                responseModel.updateTime = updateChildJsonObject.getString("updatetime");

                responseModelArrayList.add(responseModel);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ResponseModel implements Serializable {
    private String type;
    private String user;
    private String groupName;
    private String status;
    private String comments;
    private String updateTime;

}
```